# Getting objectId from parse.com

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, parse-platform

So I am building an app that uses parse as a backend.  I've written my own before but I figured I'll just save some time and use parse.  I'm populating a table view with data from parse and that's fine.  I want to grab the objectId from an dictionary built from an array from parse.

The output of my array is as follows:

```
<news_events:pdbIEvOteH:(null)> {\n    eventDescription = \"This is a test description.\";\n    eventMessage = \"This is a test message.\";\n    eventTitle = \"Free Wi-Fi Now Available!\";\n}
```

The object ID is `pdbIEvOteH` in the example above.  I at first tried getting the id by using:
`NSString * objectId = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"objectId"];`  But that returned null.  I know it is not a problem with my dictionary because I can get other information.  The problem is it looks like there is no key for `objectId` in the array above.  As you can see it follows `news_events`.

I know you can get it with the `PFObject` but I'm not sure if I can populate a table with a `PFObject`.

So bottom line is how do I get the `objectId`.

Comment: How did you create / populate the dictionary and where is the text log of the contents from?

Comment: I made a parse query which put the contents of that query into an array.  Much like creating an array from a json file.  I then used this line to create a dictionary from an array: `NSDictionary * newsAndEventsDictionary = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`.  I just used NSLog on my array to 'dump' it's contents.

Comment: "So bottom line is how do I get the objectId."

in iOS quite simply, use

something.objectId
it's that easy! You actually can not use the usual format objectForKey:

So, it's just .objectId.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, I did the following:

```
PFObject *myObject = [parseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *objectId = [myObject objectId];
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the Id of a particular PFObject.

In Swift:

```
var objectId = object.objectId
```

In Objective-C:

```
NSString *objectId = object.objectId;
```

Answer (score 0):

"So bottom line is how do I get the objectId."

following is answer from 'Joe Blow' with actual/example code for ios.

i had similar issue.  retrieving data with following code worked:

```
NSString *reporterOpinion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"reporterOpinion"]];
```

but trying to do objectForKey with objectId returned null:

```
NSString *objectId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"objectId]];
```

following 'Joe Blow' answer, the following code returned correct value for objectId:

```
NSString *objectId = object.objectId;
```