# PFUser Not returning objectID value on iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfuser

I am trying to get the `objectId` key from a `PFUser` using Parse.com, but it keeps returning null.

```
PFUser *me = [PFUser currentUser];
NSString *theObject = me[@"objectId"];
NSLog(@"Return %@", theObject);
```

Every time I run this, it comes back as "Return null".  I can put username in where I type objectId, and will get a result, but not for objectId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
NSString *theObject = [me objectId];
```

From:

[Getting objectId from parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341035/getting-objectid-from-parse-com)